# Need to group on expression in column in tablix

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report that is grouped on several fields from my dataset.  However, one of the columns in my tablix is an expression, NOT a dataset field and I don't see that expression as an option to pick when I try to add it to the detail grouping.

basically, I'm pulling the vendor's name on each order.  For one particular type of order (flower seed) one order can have several different vendors that actually supply the seed, but since it comes from us, WE really are the vendor.  So, in the column for vendor name in my tablix, I have an expression:  =IIF(Fields!major_grp.Value = "S","Seeds",Fields!vend_desc.Value) so that if it's a seed order, I make the vendor description "Seeds", otherwise I use whatever is the real value in the Field!vend_desc.value.

I need to be able to add new group expression on my calculated value, not the actual value from the dataset but it's not giving me my expression as an option to pick, just the dataset value "vend_desc".  Is it possible to group on an expression in a column of a tablix?

the only other thing I thought might be possible is to calculate the value of the vendor description in my SQL select statement in the dataset that pulls the data initially, but the Select statement I'm using is EXTREMELY complex and I'd hate to make it even muddier....

Answer (score -1):

You can create group on expression, in the group properties, where it says group on, add your expression there.

You can further look into the following links

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220419.aspx
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170712.aspx